# dynamically rectify error from java code using java program (Source Code analysis + error removal)

Tags: java, eclipse, analysis

I have been given a task where I need to convert a C# library to a java library, thus I use a utility tool (C# to Java converter) to convert the C# code to java. However, the tool is about 60% efficent in converting the code. Thus for it I need to write the program which does the rest of rectification.

To achieve it, I have used the Java Compiler API to locate errorneous code. However the error that is returned from Java compiler diagnostics is very generic, and it does not give a lot of indication to the program as to what the error and how would it be rectified?

I believe Eclipse has a quick fix (hint and solution given at compile time) which in practicality achieves the same, thus is there any way where we can use the Eclipse API to 'quick fix' out code, and if not what would be the ideal approach towards this problem?

I did look into Eclipse API but I was unable to locate the quickfix API.

Comment: I believe that for applying quick fix (which one? there might be several for one case) for the source code in "batch mode" you must implement your own eclipse plugin. This shouldn't be very difficult to do.

Comment: please remove the tag quickfix, it is not a reference to the Eclipse quickfix, rather a library for sending FIX (Financial information exchange) messages.